# Getting records of dates - no end date in some cases

Tags: sql, date, between

The database is structured as below.

```
-----------------------------------
| product | start_year | end_year |
-----------------------------------
| prod_1  |    2001    |   2005   |
| prod_2  |    2002    |   2010   |
| prod_3  |    2003    |          |
| prod_4  |    2004    |   2016   |
| prod_5  |    2005    |          |
| prod_6  |    2005    |   2015   |
-----------------------------------
```

Some fields "end_year" are empty, blank cell indicates the current year.
I have a parameter year and I want to receive the records in which the year is between two dates (start_year and end_year).

I could use this query, but unfortunately there was a problem with empty cells:

```
select * from table where 2003 between start_year and end_year;
```

Comment: I edited the question - in fact it was unclear.

Comment: In this case - year 2003 i want get the products: prod_1, prod_2, prod_3, prod_5, prod_6.

Comment: My mistake 5 and 6 is not included - my mistake.

Comment: For 2004 i want get records of products: prod_1, prod_2, prod_3, prod_4.

Comment: It's OK, but i don't get records with empty column end_year.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get the rows with year between the start_date and end_date.

Assuming if start_year is less than the given year, it should be included, you can use [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) like this:

```
select *
from your_table
where 2003 between start_year and coalesce(end_year, 9999); -- a large year value
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you want the records whose end data column as no values and start date as values .

```
 SELECT  product FROM table WHERE start_year='2003' and(end_year  IS NULL OR end_year = '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `start_year` is greater than or equal to the `searchyear` and check if `end_year` is less than or equal to `searchyear` or end_year is `NULL`

```
DECLARE @SearchYear INT=2004

SELECT Product
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE @SearchYear >= start_year AND (@StartYear >= end_year  OR end_year IS NULL)
```